# Laravel eloquent foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, php-closures

I am having a foreach loop that goes through an array, and saves data with eloquent. And it works fine when it is like this:

```
foreach($questions['questions'] as $question) {

    $questionObject = Question::create([
      'external_id' => $question['id'],
      'text' => $question['question_text'],
      'type' => $question['question_type'],
      'image' => (array_key_exists('question_image', $question)) ?
          $question['question_image'] : ''
    ]);

}
```

But when I add if condition I get undefined variable question error.

```
foreach($questions['questions'] as $question) {

    if(!$question = Question::where('id', $question['id'])->where(
        function($query){
            $query->where('updated_at','<', $question['updated']);
        }})->first()) {

        $questionObject = Question::create([
            'external_id' => $question['id'],
            'text' => $question['question_text'],
            'type' => $question['question_type'],
            'image' => (array_key_exists('question_image', $question)) ?
                $question['question_image'] : ''
        ]);
    } else {
        return 'Question: '.$question['external_id'].' already exist.';
    }
}
```

If any could help me with that, would very much appreciate that, thanks in advance!

Comment: neither your question is clear nor your error.

Comment: **!$question = Question::** ... should maybe be **$question != Question::**

Comment: Well the code in the first example works, and I get to save data in database, but when I do foreach loop with if condition, I get undefined variable question error.  And nothing gets saved in database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not injecting `$question` into your callback function. You need to use the `use` keyword:

```
if(!$question = Question::where('id', $question['id'])->where(function($query) use ($question) { $query-  >where('updated_at','<', $question['updated']); })->first()) {
```

Notice I added the `use ($question)` bit after `function($query)`

This allows `$question` to be accessed within the scope of the callback.

Comment: BTW - one-liners are not necessarily better when they make code harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using firstOrNew() ? 
Laravel documentation ->

*"The firstOrNew method, like firstOrCreate will attempt to locate a record in the database matching the given attributes. However, if a model is not found, a new model instance will be returned. Note that the model returned by firstOrNew has not yet been persisted to the database. You will need to call save manually to persist it."*

Example (using your $question value) :

```
foreach($questions['questions'] as $question) {
 $questionObject = Question::firstOrNew(
                array(
          'external_id' => $question['id'],
          'text' => $question['question_text'],
          'type' => $question['question_type'],
          'image' =>$question['question_image'] 

                )
        );

$questionObject->external_id = $question['id'];
$questionObject->text = $question['text'];
.
.
.
$questionObject->save();

}
```